# Arguments and functions in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to use argurments of a first tizkset to give them to a second tikset.This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/message/.style={code={
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,1);
\draw foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(\X,0) -- (\X,1)}; 
%someone gave me two lines and i can't figure out how they work
\foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {\Y-0.5}] in {#1} %1
{\node at (\Z,0.5) {\X}; %2
\ifnum\Y=4
\breakforeach 
\fi}
}}}
\tikzset{pics/broadcast/.style={code={\begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,5);
\pic at (1,3) {message={1,2,3,4}};
\end{scope}
}}}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {message={1,2,3,4}}; %instead it should be the params of broadcast
\pic at (0,3) {broadcast};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To draw me this:

[image]

I would like to call rectangle like that:

```
\pic at (0,0) {broadcast={1,2,3,4}};
```

While changing this line in the broadcast method:

```
\pic at (1,3) {message={1,2,3,4}}; %actually
\pic at (1,3) {message={%every param of broadcast%}}; % What I want
```

How can I do this?

Comment: For me it is not very clear what you want : inside your `broadcast` pic you have a nested `message` pic, do you want to be able to passe the parameters of `broadcast` to the nested `message` ? If this is the case you can simply remove your `scope` (with the unused `local bounding box=#1`) and replace `\pic at (1,3) {message={1,2,3,4}};` with `\pic at (1,3) {message={#1}};`.

Comment: @Kpym Did you *try* what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal. It is not absolutely fool proof. In its present form, if you call a message pic and a broadcast pic afterwards, the message gets broadcasted. To intercept broadcasting, use `\broadcastfalse` after the message pic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifbroadcast
\broadcastfalse
\tikzset{pics/message/.style={code={\xdef\LastMessage{#1}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,1);
\draw foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(\X,0) -- (\X,1)}; 
%someone gave me two lines and i can't figure out how they work
\ifbroadcast
 \foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {\Y-0.5}] in #1 %1
 {\node at (\Z,0.5) {\X}; %2
 \ifnum\Y=4
 \breakforeach 
 \fi}
\else
 \foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {\Y-0.5}] in {#1} %1
 {\node at (\Z,0.5) {\X}; %2
 \ifnum\Y=4
 \breakforeach 
 \fi}
\fi
}}}
\tikzset{pics/broadcast/.style={code={\begin{scope}[local bounding box=#1]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,5);
\ifx\LastMessage\empty
\pic at (1,3) {message};
\else
\broadcasttrue
\pic at (1,3) {message=\LastMessage};
\fi
\end{scope}
}}}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {message={1,2,3,4}}; %instead it should be the params of broadcast
\pic at (0,3) {broadcast};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]